# How to speed up NiFi boot time

Tags: apache-nifi

I wanted to know can we speed up the NiFi boot time, as in most of the cases we need to test NiFi from locally on our machine but it takes almost 10 mins to start properly.

Highly appreciated, if someone can help with this.

- I am using NiFi 1.8

Comment: what nifi version you are using?

Comment: A generic build of NiFi should start in approximately 18-20 seconds on a commodity laptop, and a cluster should start up in < 5 minutes by default (less time if configuration changes are made to reduce the wait time). What is happening in your `nifi-app.log` file that indicates this is taking 10 minutes?

Comment: The first step would be to look into the app log files, the GC log, and to profile the staring application. Oh, this is coming from July, sorry. Did you find a solution to your problem? If yes, please do share it with us and any other NiFi users who're looking for a similar thing.